# How to return the difference between two struct values in a third struct?

Tags: c, function, struct, structure

Please read the following code and guide me on how do I return the int elapsedTime as a struct type as the third time struct e.g. time3 and display it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>>
#include <math.h>

#include "Time.h"

void elapsedTime(struct time time1, struct time time2); // Prototype

int main(){

    struct time time1 = {3, 45, 15};
    struct time time2 = {9, 44, 03};

    elapsedTime(time1, time2);

    return 0;
}


void elapsedTime(struct time time1, struct time time2){

    int elapsedTime = ((time1.Hours * MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR * 
    SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) + (time1.Minutes * SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) + 
    time1.Seconds) - ((time2.Hours * MINUTES_IN_AN_HOUR * 
    SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) + (time2.Minutes * SECONDS_IN_A_MINUTE) + 
    time2.Seconds);

    printf(" %d \n", abs(elapsedTime));
    return;
}
```

Structure in header file:

```
struct time{
    int Hours;
    int Seconds;
    int Minutes;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division is your friend. You'll need to do something like:

```
result.Hours = et / 3600;
et -= (result.Hours * 3600);
result.Minutes = et / 60;
et -= (result.Minutes * 60);
result.Seconds = et;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but now how do I return the result in the military time format in a new structure?

Comment: We're not here to teach basic programming. Learn the language.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for your help.